# Java: stopping "for" loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm struggling with an assignment about loops in Java.

We were asked to write a program that ask the user the input "int in = input.nextInt" then multiply it by the input number each time until the variable reachs 100.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int in = input.nextInt();
for(int x = 0; x < 99;)                    
{
   x = x + in;
   System.out.println(x);                  
}
```

The problem is, this algorithm allows the multiple value to reach over 100 within 6 to 8 multiplications.

How do I configure the for loop to restrict the number from being printed if its value is over 100? I've tried to dabble with Boolean operators in the conditional statement but no dice. I am certainly missing something here.

Comment: First output, then increment?

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Personal preference - but I do think a while loop is the better choice here from a readability perspective:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int in = input.nextInt();
int x = in; // first iteration outside of the while loop, since x is 0 on init
while(x < 99)                    
{
   System.out.println(x); 
   x = x + in;                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to increment variable `x` in `for` loop:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int in = input.nextInt();
for (int x = 0; x < 99; x += in) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: `x += in` is the same as `x = x + in`.

Comment: `x += in` is equivalent to `x = x + in`

Answer (score 0):

I would say that since you need not to print the number if it is greater than 99, you could write the for as follows

```
for (int x = 0; x + in < 99; )
{
    x = x + in;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Obviously this could be optimized, but you should try!